# How to populate UIPickerView with JSON array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uipickerview

I'm trying to populate my UIPickerView with a JSON array for categories. I need to return results based on the selection from the picker. How do I do so?

Comment: Why the vote down? It's a valid question!

Comment: Its a question that you are not the first one to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement UIPickerViewDatasource & UIPickerViewDelegate protocols

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{ 
    return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row 
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0)
         return @"What";
    if (component == 1)
         return @"have";
    if (component == 3)
         return @"you";
    if (component == 4)
         return @"tried";
    return @"?";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!! Wish I could vote up, but do not have enough reputation points.